# Trouble generating CXF client code (wsdl2java) with Axis2 service

Tags: jaxb, cxf, apache-axis, wsdl2java

So I have a vendor app that created all of their services with Axis2.  For whatever reason, if I generate the client code using Axis2's WSDL2Java, it works just dandy, but whenever I use CXF to generate it, I get errors all over the place, and I don't know how to make CXF **work**:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.cxf:cxf-codegen-plugin:2.6.0:wsdl2java (generate-sources) on project unitoffers: Thrown by JAXB:
[ERROR] Thrown by JAXB:
[ERROR] undefined simple or complex type 'xs:EJBException'
[ERROR] at line 1760 column 21 of schema file:/C:/Users/Me/myproject/src/main/resources/wsdl/ObjectHierarchy.wsdl
[ERROR]
[ERROR] undefined simple or complex type 'xs:EJBException'
[ERROR] at line 1831 column 21 of schema file:/C:/Users/Me/myproject/src/main/resources/wsdl/ObjectHierarchy.wsdl
[ERROR]
[ERROR] undefined simple or complex type 'xs:EJBException'
[ERROR] at line 1852 column 21 of schema file:/C:/Users/Me/myproject/src/main/resources/wsdl/ObjectHierarchy.wsdl
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
```

Is Axis2 doing something really funky that CXF can't interpret?  As mentioned, I can generate the code with Axis2, but almost all of my other services are CXF, and I'd prefer not to mix-and-match services in my projects (not to mention that some projects would require having BOTH Axis2 and CXF in order to work, so that would make things messy).

Comment: Yeah, I've found CXF just works better for most things I'm doing, but I'd hate to be forced to use axis2 because it's the only one that can talk fluent "axis" dialect to the service.